# Scipy lognormal CFD and SF give me 0 most of the time

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

According to [Scipy reference](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.lognorm.html), given a `lognormal distribution`, the `CDF` gives the probability of X being at or below a certain value, and `SF` gives the probability of X being above a certain value.

Since my distribution is centered in x=195, I am using the loc parameter when calling those functions. I am not using the scale parameter. The problem might be here, due to a bad interpretation of how these two parameters work.

So, I wrote a small code in order to determine the probability of `x` being between two values `x1` and `x2`, where `x1<x2`:

```
from scipy.stats import lognorm

sigma = 0.149
mu = 195
x1 = 188.78
x2 = 201.68
p_below = lognorm.cdf(x1, sigma, loc=mu)
p_above = lognorm.sf(x2, sigma, loc=mu)
p_between = 1 - p_above - p_below
```

I would say that, being at `x=195` which such a low variance, the probability of `x` being below `x1` or above `x2` would be high. Nevertheless, the values returned by `cdf` and `sf` are zero most of the times. I only succeeded getting a sf result greater than zero when lowering `sigma` down to `0.068`, which is weird (with more variance, easier to get out of bounds). Moreover, I would never expect `cdf` or `sf` to return zero, but a very low positive `float` instead.

Any idea of what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Let's see:

```
In [41]: st.lognorm.sf(x2-mu, s=sigma)
Out[41]: 0.0

In [42]: a = np.log(x2-mu) / sigma

In [43]: st.norm.sf(a)
Out[43]: 1.6458720667149256e-37

In [44]: st.norm.logsf(a)
Out[44]: -84.697378065290948
```

But

```
In [45]: st.norm.cdf(a)
Out[45]: 1.0
```

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.17.0/scipy/stats/_continuous_distns.py#L3000), it gets clear that the implementation of scipy.lognorm can be improved by defining explicit _sf, _logcdf and _logsf methods to forward to the corresponding methods of the normal distribution just like `_cdf` does.

For now, the workaround is to take the log manually and use `scipy.stats.norm` methods.

EDIT: Here's the scipy ticket: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/5940
(patches welcome!)

EDIT2: This has been fixed in the scipy master branch:

```
In [19]: scipy.__version__
Out[19]: '0.18.0.dev0+f63d0a6'

In [20]: lognorm.sf(x2-mu, s=sigma)
Out[20]: 1.6458720667149256e-37
```

EDIT3: There is still a problem in the snippet from OP: `1 - 1.e-37` equals one in the floating point.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same problem in scipy, i.e. the sf and cdf functions are not very accurate and only allow for probabilities of ~10^-30 before becoming 0.  As an alternative you can try to perform numerical integration, perhaps using scipy/numpy or mpmath (http://mpmath.org/doc/current/calculus/integration.html).

Alternatively, you can try to reformulate your problem so that you can use another statistic for you test.  That's how I solved my problem.  However, this may not always be an option.

Comment: I don't think that the probability of x being between below 189 or above 201 is so low that I need further precission than ~10^-30.